Suppose that $f$ is a nonnegative function that is Riemann Integrable on [a,b]. Prove that $\sqrt{f}$ is also Riemann Integrable on [a,b]
I have a Real Analysis final on Monday and I'm working through some practice problems in an old textbook that I found at a used book store. I saw a solution to the problem here that used the fact that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is a continuous function, but I would like to prove it without that.
On my own, I tried manipulating until I got that $\sqrt{\sup\{f\}} - \sqrt{\inf\{f\}} = \frac{\sup\{f\} - \inf\{f\}}{\sqrt{\sup\{f\}} + \sqrt{\inf\{f\}}}$.
While I know that I can bound the top by $\varepsilon$ due to $f$ being integrable, I was struggling on how to bound the bottom.
I don't know if this is the right approach to proving this, but any help would be very much appreciated.

Perhaps use the fact that $\sqrt{f}$ is Lipschitz on any compact subset of $x>0$?

If $f$ is often very near $0$, that equation won't be very helpful. In fact, $f=0$ satisfies the conditions and breaks that attempt.

@copper.hat, we haven't gone over what it means for a function to be Lipschitz

@aschepler Yeah I was imagining I would have to some sort of case work to prevent this. Should I try to tackle the problem differently rather than bounding like this then?
